# Send SSL requests to localhost:port using apache

Tags: web-server, proxypass, apache2, meteor

I'm running a meteor application, due to restrictions I must use Apache as the webserver. There are also other existing websites hosted on the same domain under different locations e.g. `https://example.com/phpsite1`, `https://example.com/phpsite2`.

The application I'm interested in runs on `http://localhost:3000`.

Essentially I would like to have a new location on the same domain, `https://example.com/mymeteorapp` where requests to this page map to `http://localhost:3000`.

I've been playing with proxypass but struggling to get something working. Any help or examples would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic reverse proxy syntax would be set up within a `<Location>` tag in the Apache config. Something like:

```
<Location "/mymeteorapp1/">
  ProxyPass "http://localhost:3000/"
</Location>
```

Should do what you want. This will strip everything off after the `/mymeteorapp1/` and  feed it to the backend application running on port 3000. The documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass provides some very clear examples.

Comment: thanks! due to routing in the meteor application i couldn't use the location `"/mymeteorapp1/"` i had to use `"/"`. also to make sure i could access the other php sites at different locations i needed to add `ProxyPass /phplocation !`